# Change the /accounts/ url to be shorter (/acc/) in Django?

Tags: django

I was just wondering if its safe to shorten the `/accounts/` url that is the (suggested?) default in the `django.contrib.auth`

Does anything behind the scenes depend on that url being `/accounts/`... for user authentication etc?

Thanks

Comment: Not an issue. Django uses a concept called named URLs to prevent issues when you alter the URI. -More on the concept: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns